# Why/how does the browser decide ☃.net goes to xn--n3h.net

Tags: url, browser, unicode, punycode, iri

If we type into firefox or chrome

[`http://☃.net/`](http://%E2%98%83.net/)

It takes us to

[`http://xn--n3h.net/`](http://xn--n3h.net/)

Which is a mirror of [unicodesnowmanforyou.com](http://unicodesnowmanforyou.com)

What I don't understand is by what rules the unicode snowman can decode to `xn--n3h`, it doesn't look anything like utf-8 or urlencoding.

I think I found a hint while mucking around in python3, because:

```
>>> '☃'.encode('punycode')
b'n3h'
```

But I still don't understand the `xn--` part.  How are domain names internationalised, what is the standard and where is this stuff documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses an encoding scheme called Punycode (as you've already discovered from the Python testing you've done), capable of representing Unicode characters in ASCII-only format.

Each label (delimited by dots, so `get.me.a.coffee.com` has five labels) that contains Unicode characters is encoded in Punycode and prefixed with the string `xn--`.

The label encoding first copies all the ASCII characters, then appends the encoded Unicode characters. The Unicode characters are always after the final `-` in the label, so one is added after the ASCII characters if needed.

More detail can be found in [this page](http://www.w3.org/International/articles/idn-and-iri/) over at the w3 site, and in [RFC 3987](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987). For details on how Punycode actually encodes labels, see [the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode).

Comment: Ah, good.  I understand now, `xn--` is not an encoding per-se, it's a specification.  Appears to be called the "ACE prefix" for any googlers finding this post.

Comment: Yes, `xn--` is an **ASCII Compatible Encoding (ACE) prefix** to let the DNS system know that the rest of the label is punycode-encoded. In your example, `n3h` is the Punycode-encoded form of `☃`.